# Comparing time differences to text embedded cells

Tags: excel, time, comparison

I have two columns, F and G which contain date and time stamps together. I need to compare the two cells to calculate the time duration (Cell G -Cell F essentially). The issue is I cannot use a simple formula (it appears) due to the date and time being in the same cell and complexity of the content, to pinpoint the characters I need to compare. Any help appreciated. (The last 6 characters can be ignored)

Example of both cells:

> Column F:2018-07-27T20:34:27+01:00
>
> Column G:2018-07-27T20:35:14+01:00

An outcome of xdays, xhours, xminutes, xseconds would be great, or just the time not the days if that is not possible.

Comment: Just a thought, but ignoring the time zone information could be risky, if the times could come from different sources.

Comment: your data has fixed length so you can simply use MID, LEFT & CONCAT to get the time and date like `"2018-07-27 20:34:27"` and subtract them to get duration. Also apply format `[h]:mm:ss` on duration to get proper duration.

Comment: To expand on what @Srijan said: I think the main issue is that Excel doesn't recognize that format as a DateTime value because it contains a T and the timezone information. Strip that off and you can use normal operators on them. If your data contains multiple time zones, you could look at splitting that out and applying the proper time zone shifts as well.

Comment: Thank you all. SRIJAN, that looks like the right approach.